# Keeping the footer on the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I know this is a common issue but I just can't work this out. No matter how many combinations of settings I try, the footer won't stay on the bottom of the page. It will just sit under whatever else is above it.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ACFAB7;
}

# container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
}

#header {
  z-index: 0;
  height: 78px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

#footer {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  /*display required to center text*/
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#image {
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

/*Centers text within the header*/
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: make #footer position:absolute and add bottom:0px to it.

Comment: Further @sagarkodte comment, just keep attention in large pages that you need to cancel the `position`. If your website is public it will be eaiser for us to check our self.

Comment: Consider using flexbox over absolute positioning.

Comment: Although the easiest answer is the **fixed** attribute, if you don't want that, there is a pure CSS way to achieve what you want. For instance: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: Find this http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/.. you can do this without making `absolute` or `fixed` your footer will also go down depending your content height.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of problems. This solution is for:

- Fixing your footer at the end of the page.
- Centering the contents (both vertically and horizontally).

**Fixes**

- Get rid of `display: table`.
- Get rid of `width: 100%`.
- Change `relative` to `fixed`.

```css
#footer {
  z-index: 2;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">Copyrights.</div>
```

Comment: @AdnanAkram Ah? Why? Interesting. I have used this way a lot of times. What's the problem with this solution? Eager to understand. Thanks.

Comment: if we have footer with a height of 200px then if we use position: fixed; it take a lot of space and it always stick on the bottom of browser so display:table; is perfect

Comment: @AdnanAkram Thanks for the info. But how does having `display: table` help? Also we aren't supposed to use `table` or any other derivatives for layout right? Not a good web development, if that's been used. `:)` Agree?

Comment: i agree we can not use 'table' as layout, but we go with best approach according to requirement, you can check code here we can make footer at bottom with fixed height and with flexible height https://jsfiddle.net/8cewhr5g/     and here is the flexible height version https://jsfiddle.net/9fLc1djm/

Comment: @AdnanAkram Thanks I feel like I learnt something new. Lemme have a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed; bottom: 0`;

```css
#footer {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;  
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `display: table` and other things?

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed;` and `bottom: 0;` should do the trick. Add width and height as neccessary.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: lightgrey;height: 800px">
  Page content
</div>
<div class="footer">
  this is the footer
</div>
```

Comment: When the content's `height` is more than the window, then it stands in the middle. Have you tried this?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: thanks for pointing it out. i updated the code using `position: fixed`